# How to copy multiple lines and paste at the end of a file

Tags: cut-copy-paste, multiple-lines

Suppose I have a file:

```
class X(arg):
\t#blabbla
\tdef fun1(arg):
\t\tsome code
\n
\tdef fun2(arg):
\t\tsome code
\n
class A(arg):
\t#blabbla
\tdef fun0(arg):
\t\tsome code
\n
\tdef fun3(arg):
\t\tsome code
```

And I wish to copy all lines start with `class` and `\tdef`, and paste them to the end of file preserving the order, i.e.

```
class X(arg):
\tdef fun1(arg):
\tdef fun2(arg):
class A(arg):
\tdef fun0(arg):
\tdef fun3(arg):
```

How can I achieve that without using extra plug-ins? (\t is tab, \n is new line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want to perform (copy and paste or cut and paste), you could try one of the 2 following commands:

```
:g/\v^(class|\tdef)/t$
:g/\v^(class|\tdef)/m$
```

---

To duplicate (copy and paste) the current line after the last one, you can use the `:t` command: `:t$`

Like most Ex commands `:t` can be prefixed with an optional range, and like most Ex commands, when you don't give one, the current line is assumed.
So `:t$` is the same as `:.t$` or `:.,.t$`

The `:t` command must be followed by a line address which is the number of the line after which the duplicated lines must be pasted.

With these 2 informations, you can perform an arbitrary duplication, such as: `:5,10t42`
Copy the lines between `5` and `10` and paste them below the line `42`.

When you express a line address, there are some useful symbols (called specifiers by the help) such as:

```
.      current line
$      last line
'x     line where the mark x has been last set
/foo/  next line where foo is found
```

See `:help :range` for a comprehensive list of specifiers.

---

To move (cut and paste) the current line after the last one, you can use the `:move` command: `:m$`

---

In your question, you want to repeat the same command `:t$` or `:m$` on a set of lines where the same pattern can be found.
Usually, this is a job for the global command `:g`.

So, you could use the command: `:g/pattern/t$` or `:g/pattern/m$`
It would execute `:t$` or `:m$` on every line where `pattern` is found.

Besides, you want to operate on all the lines which begin with the word `class`, or with a hard tab followed by the word `def`.
In a regex, it could be expressed like this: `\v^(class|\tdef)`

Thus, the command `:g/pattern/t$` should be rewritten, like this: `:g/\v^(class|\tdef)/t$`
And `:g/pattern/m$` like this: `:g/\v^(class|\tdef)/m$`

If you execute the first command on your buffer, here's the transformation you should get (assuming there's an empty line at the end):

```
class X(arg):               class X(arg):     
    #blabbla                    #blabbla      
    def fun1(arg):              def fun1(arg):
        some code                   some code 

    def fun2(arg):              def fun2(arg):
        some code                   some code 

class A(arg):         ==>   class A(arg):     
    #blabbla                    #blabbla      
    def fun0(arg):              def fun0(arg):
        some code                   some code 

    def fun3(arg):              def fun3(arg):
        some code                   some code 

                            class X(arg):     
                                def fun1(arg):
                                def fun2(arg):
                            class A(arg):     
                                def fun0(arg):
                                def fun3(arg):
```

---

More generally, when you want to copy or cut a set of lines and paste them at the end of your buffer, you can follow a 2-steps process:

1. progressively build a search pattern until your search matches the desired lines
2. type `:g//t$` or `:g//m$`

It works because, when you don't supply a pattern to the global or substitute command, they reuse the last search (the one in the search register `:reg /`).

---

For more information, see:

```
:help :global
:help :t (or :copy)
:help :move
```